# Explicação sobre código PHP

Tags: php

Boa noite, alguém com mais afinidade em PHP poderia explicar o seguinte code?

PS: Estou iniciando os estudos então já peço desculpas caso a dúvida seja frívola.

```
<?php

        if (isset($_GET['pagina'])) {
            $do = ($_GET['pagina']);
        }else{
            $do = "inicio";
        }

        if (file_exists("paginas/" .$do. ".php")) {
            include("paginas/" .$do. ".php");
        }else{
            echo "Página não econtrada";
        }

?>
```

Comment: Curto e grosso, é um baita problema de segurança.

Comment: Basicamente ele executa o arquivo php que for passado na url. Inclusive arquivos que uma pessoa qualquer na internet não deveria poder mandar executar.

Comment: @bfavaretto é mais propício a haver isso, sim, mas acho que se o programador souber o faz, somente páginas mesmo dentro do diretório `páginas` não há prob. Ps: eu também não faria assim claro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explicações estão nos comentários abaixo no código:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['pagina'])) { // verifica se a variável $_GET['pagina'] foi iniciada e definida recebendo dado da variável 'pagina'
   $do = ($_GET['pagina']); // foi iniciada e definida, atribui ela à variável $do
}else{ // a variável $_GET['pagina'] não foi iniciada, então a variável $do ganha o valor "inicio"
   $do = "inicio";
}

if (file_exists("paginas/" .$do. ".php")) { // verifica se o arquivo vindo da variável $do existe concatenando com as strings do caminho do arquivo
   include("paginas/" .$do. ".php"); // carrega a página no documento
}else{ // página não existe no caminho especificado acima
   echo "Página não econtrada"; // imprime o texto na tela
}
?>
```

> Use também o `!empty($_GET['pagina'])`. O `isset` é válidado se a variável `pagina` for vazia ou igual a 0.

```
if ( isset($_GET['pagina']) && !empty($_GET['pagina']) ){
```

Comment: Não quer acrescentar o objetivo final desses passos todos? Um alerta sobre a vulnerabilidade desse código também ia bem.